# Streaming MP3 audio to HTML5 audio tag from servlet

Tags: ruby, html, cross-browser, mp3, html5-audio

I'm having some cross-browser compatibility joys. I have a Ruby WEBrick server with a couple of servlets, one of which is used to stream media (Ogg and MP3). The servlet gets a couple of query parameters (a base64 urlsafe string `key`, a small string `user`, and a small number, `sid`). When I put the URL verbatim into Chrome, I get the QuickTime extension, and it works. When I post the same into FireFox, I get the expected unsupported codec. When I put it in Safari, it works. However, the URL is not being accessed directly. I have a jQuery Mobile app that uses the Javascript [Buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) library, and uses these servlet streaming URLs as sources. The code works in Safari, allowing me to play the sounds. On FireFox, instead of falling back onto Ogg, it gives unsupported errors, and on Chrome, it does nothing. Here's the code that serves the MP3:

```
res.status = 200
str = File.new("Music/#{req.query['sid']}.mp3", 'r:BINARY:BINARY').read
res.body = str
res['content-type'] = 'audio/mpeg'
```

Can anyone tell me how to get audio streaming to all browsers through a Ruby servlet?

Note: This is not a duplicate. I've been thorough a lot of SO answers, but none work because they are designed for static files, not servlets.